# Examples of ergodic geodesic flow

Tags: differential-geometry, examples-counterexamples, ergodic-theory

Are there any good examples of a geodesic flow that is ergodic? I know the result that states that the geodesic flow for manifolds with negative curvature are ergodic, but I'm fishing for some insightful examples.

Comment: The hamiltonian flow is ergodic. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(Hamiltonian)

Comment: Can you be more specific? I don't think it's true that the Hamiltonian flow is always ergodic; consider billiards on a circular domain.

Comment: The canonical measure is invariant by the hamiltonian flow.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I follow. Wouldn't that just mean that the Hamiltonian flow is measure-preserving?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I thought that this was your definition of ergodicity, at least this was the one that I heard in a seminar.

Answer (score 2):

The geodesic flow I'm most familiar with is billiards on a polygon. [This paper](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1971280?uid=2&uid=4&sid=21103206166537) gives a description of the geodesic flow corresponding to the motion of a billiard ball, and proves that for almost all right triangles the flow is ergodic. It has also been proven that the flow is ergodic for almost all polygons, but I don't have the reference on hand.

Comment: Thanks. This is very useful, I remember that billiards on the Sinai and Bunimovich stadiums are also ergodic. But are there any examples whose justification is shorter?

Comment: @user118639 The Sinai example is much easier than this one unfortunately. I'm afraid this is the only ergodic system I'm really familiar with.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the $n$-torus $\mathbb T^n$, where $\mathbb T = [0,1]$ with $0$ identified with $1$ (i.e. $\mathbb T$ is homeomorphic to the circle).  Then I believe the map given by the flow $\varphi_t(x) = x+t u \pmod 1$, where the coordinates of $u$ are independent over the rationals, is ergodic.

For example $\varphi_t(x_1,x_2) = ((x_1+t)\bmod 1,(x_2+t\sqrt 2)\bmod 1)$.

And the flow is clearly geodesic if we use the flat metric.